# Is there an English translation of the German book "Einführung in die Kombinatorische und die Geometrische Gruppentheorie"?

Tags: group-theory, cryptography, combinatorial-group-theory, translation-request, mathematical-german

In a recent publication called "*Secure passwords using combinatorial group theory*," by G. Baumslag *et al.*, it says that the following book is a "standard reference" in combinatorial group theory.

Camps, Gr Rebel and Rosenberger, ["*Einführung in die Kombinatorische und die Geometrische Gruppentheorie*"](https://www.amazon.de/Einf%C3%BChrung-kombinatorische-geometrische-Gruppentheorie-Studienreihe/dp/3885381192).

> Is there an English translation of this book?

I couldn't find one. Please help :)

Comment: [This translation of a different German book](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.3906?fbclid=IwAR0LTquHQtlBMHvUgjon6kGYTazxcaMx2XhJAvA5QYhy2EO7mWgk8jPVLG4), the first monograph in combinatorial group theory in fact, is the closest thing I've found; I think it's worth providing a link to it here.

Comment: Is there a specific thing which you want to look up in this book? The paper uses the book for two things: (1) the definition of a Nielsen transformation (look up Magnus, Karrass and Solitar), and (2) the word problem and subgroup membership problem are soluble for free groups. Again see MKS for the word problem; for the subgroup membership problem I suggest using Stallings' foldings (see Stallings, *Topology of finite graphs", Invent. Math., 1980s). I also suggest reading the papers of, for example, Myasnikov who (a) likes Stallings' foldings and (b) cares about computational complexity.

Comment: (Also, I do not want to imply bad things about the authors here - 3 of them are extremely well known and respected - but your alarm bells should be ringing when you are looking at this paper! In particular, it took about 5 weeks from submission to acceptance (then you google [the publisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Research_Publishing)). A second alarm bell should ring when you remember that the first author passed away over 3 years before original submission. [These are just alarm bells - papers can be processed quickly, and it is not unknown for deceased people to publish!])

Comment: (My point, however, is that when these alarm bells are ringing you should take subjective claims, like that a book which is 10 years old and written by one of the authors is "standard", with a pinch of salt.)